# Redundant application.js and css after precompile assets in development with Rail 3.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I precompile assets before deploy to production. Production mode is work well, but the application.js and application.css redundant in development. I try to `rake assets:clean` and remove all of the public assets still didn't work.

## The view in development

Redundant applicaiton.css and application.js

```
<link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-custom-lastest.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/animate.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/jquery_loadmask/jquery_loadmask.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
...
<script src="/assets/tags.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/wedapp.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/works.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

## development.rb

```
config.assets.compress = false
config.assets.debug = true
```

## production.rb

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.compile = true  
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false  
config.assets.digest = true
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx
```

Now, I need to set false in config.assets.debug at development.rb, but I can't debug assets before precompile. This's really bother me.

Any suggestions? thanks.

## Solution

Try to change application.js file anything, I delete one blank line and `rake assets:clean RAILS_ENV=development`, it works well now.

Comment: what do you mean by application.js/css are redundant?

Comment: To @FrederickCheung, application.js and application.css should not load in development with 'config.assets.debug=true'.

Comment: Don't think that's true since it's legal (but discouraged) to have js/CSS in those files rather than them being pure manifest files.

Answer (score 0):

if you are precompiling locally, and want to retain all the normal development mode functionality, then you can tweak your settings to allow both.

In development.rb place the following line:

```
config.assets.prefix = "/dev-assets"
```

This over-rides whatever is set in application.rb (normally "/assets").

You will also need this in application.rb:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

You can then commit your compiled assets to source control and deploy them and not have to worry about cleaning them up afterwards.

(See my [full blog post](http://richardhulse.blogspot.co.nz/2012/03/rails-how-to-compile-and-commit-assets.html) on the topic)

Comment: hi @Richard Hulse, I set up the config as you say, but the page still redundant from /assets/... to /dev-assets/...